# LLVM error out of memory when running tensorflow code

Tags: out-of-memory, llvm, attention-model

I want to implement an attention mechanism to perform a speech recognition task using PyCharm on Ubuntu 16.04. My machine has 16 GB RAM and two 1070Ti GPUs.

Unfortunately, the following code always outputs "LLVM error:out of memory":

```py
    def attention(self, x_i, x, index):
        """
        Attention model for speech recognition
        :param x_i: the embedded input at time i
        :param x: the embedded input of all times(x_j of attentions)
        :param index: step of time
        """

        e_i = []
        c_i = []
        for output in x:
            output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.embedding_size])
            atten_hidden = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x_i, self.attention_W), tf.matmul(output, self.attention_U)))
            e_i_j = tf.matmul(atten_hidden, self.attention_V)
            e_i.append(e_i_j)
        e_i = tf.concat(e_i, axis=1)
        # e_i = tf.exp(e_i)
        alpha_i = tf.nn.softmax(e_i)
        alpha_i = tf.split(alpha_i, self.sequence_length, 1)

        # i!=j
        for j, (alpha_i_j, output) in enumerate(zip(alpha_i, x)):
            if j == index:
                continue
            else:
                output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.embedding_size])
                c_i_j = tf.multiply(alpha_i_j, output)
                c_i.append(c_i_j)
        c_i = tf.reshape(tf.concat(c_i, axis=1), [-1, self.sequence_length-1, self.embedding_size])
        c_i = tf.reduce_sum(c_i, 1)
        return c_i
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue using TensorFlow and Keras. The only thing I noticed is that you are still using a very old Ubuntu version. Do you have any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

1. you may be need to add more RAM to the machine
2. you could try an official attention mechanism